# last command session duration syntaxe

Tags: linux

Very simple question here, i was wondering about the **last** command and the final column which is the "login status" still logged or down with the duration of the session

```
ext pts/7        10.1.24.88       Tue Sep 28 16:53 - 16:02 (18+23:08)
ext pts/6        10.1.24.88       Tue Sep 28 16:11 - 16:02 (18+23:50)
```

For this case : `(18+23:08)` i don't understand the syntax with the +, someone can help me translate the `18+23:08` ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

[`+` separates days and hours](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/login-utils/last.c?id=79fb7e18f45e84c6f1a030b5df56cb2bdad26df0#n473): “18+23:08” means 18 days, 23 hours and 8 minutes.